# What is the appropriate place / approach to request permissions on app launch?

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I have some basic functions in my app that I know will need some permissions pretty much as soon as the app starts, or at least very shortly after. It makes perfect sense to request them on app startup (and I've seen many apps do that, presumably for the same reason). However, I cannot find a suitable place to call `requestPermissions`. I tried doing that in my `Activity.onResume`, but that proved to be a very bad idea because for some reason, even when the permission is already granted and there's no prompt pop-up, `requestPermissions` pauses the activity shortly and resumes it back, so my request causes recursion.

What's the right approach? I don't think `onCreate` would work, seems a bit early in the life cycle. Or is that indeed the place?

Comment: `onCreate()` can work, though it suffers from the same recursion issue that your `onResume()` approach does. With appropriate state tracking, you can avoid the recursion -- see [this sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.4/ConferenceVideos).